# How to write an Android SocketServer to listen on wifi

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

I've written a thread using `java.net.SocketServer` to listen on a particular port. It works fine in the android simulator (using port forwarding). I'm planning to connect over wifi to this port when the app is being used. However, the `SocketServer` documentation says that if you don't supply an `InetAddress`, the server listens on localhost.

Am I correct that if I do not supply the address, I will not be able to get a connection over wifi? How can I get the `InetAddress` of the wifi connection to pass to the `SocketServer`?

Answer (score 17):

When you create a ServerSocket you listen to a *port* on the *localhost*. It's up to you if you want to nominate your own [local host address](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress)).

Read these two articles:

- [Implement a simple Socket Server in Eclipse](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/implement-simple-socket-server-in.html)
- [Simple communication using java.net.Socket](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html)

Remember to have a [WiFi lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) and the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I didn't know about the wifi lock. I've got a working server app like the pages you suggest. What I'm confused about is that if I use a language like C or Python to write a server and bind to the localhost, I can only connect from the localhost. I'm unclear whether SocketServer on android binds to all IP addresses or only to the localhost addresss.

Comment: Listening to all IpAddresses is power & CPU consuming. Of course it only listens to the localhost (or an ipaddress nominated by you explicitly)

Comment: I think you are not understanding what I mean by binding to an address - there's no extra power used for binding to all addresses! Anyway, the SocketServer appears to bind to the wifi address of a test phone I have tried. It doesn't bind only to a localhost loopback address.

Comment: My bad, I should have used the word bind instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

private String getIPAddress() throws SocketException {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info == null || !info.isConnected()){
            return null;
        }

        switch (info.getType()) {
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI: {
                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                if (wifi == null) break;
                WifiInfo wifi_info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
                String ipAddress = intToIp(wifi_info.getIpAddress());
                return ipAddress;
            }
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE: {
                Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaceEnumerations =  NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
                while(interfaceEnumerations.hasMoreElements()){
                    NetworkInterface interfac = interfaceEnumerations.nextElement();
                    Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = interfac.getInetAddresses();
                    while(inetAddresses.hasMoreElements()){
                        InetAddress address = inetAddresses.nextElement();
                        if (!address.isLoopbackAddress() && !address.isLinkLocalAddress()) {
                            String addressIp = address.getHostAddress();
                            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(addressIp) || !addressIp.matches("(\\d{1,3}.){3}\\d{1,3}")) continue;
                            return addressIp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```