# Sharing image from Android device to other via WiFi

Tags: android, wifi

I want to Create an Android Application that shares Device's Image Gallery by connecting WiFi Connection to Another Android Device ( like http://192.168.1.7:8080 ).

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054076/how-to-write-an-android-socketserver-to-listen-on-wifi  It does not cover HTTP protocol, but all the other stuff needed to make the Android device a server other phones can connect to.

Comment: For some devices, I think [WiFi Direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) maybe a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use this P2P library :-

http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/alljoyn-p2p

it provides communications between android devices , so you can share images  also using this library