# turn an android phone into a joypad and connect it to the computer via wi-Fi

Tags: java, android, c, embedded, hardware

I am trying to make a joypad for android that has the accelerometer based directional control. So far I have been succesful in completing the android portion. Now I need to interface the computer I/O port for joypad using Wi-Fi. I have no idea of how to do this. I need embedded system programming knowledge for this. But I don't even know where to start? In fact I even don't know if this is possible or not?? I have searched though internet and found a lot about connection using parallel port or serial port.But every page says that you have to have a parallel port female connector to do this (*Nowadays parallel port connector are extinct as USB have replaced them*). I know that I don't need to connect to any of these external connectors of pins as I am working through Wi-Fi.

1. Is this possible for what I am trying to build??
2. How do I access to the I/O port by using Wi-Fi (without having to connect anything external to the ports)??
3. Is it possible to transfer data between android (java) and computer (C embedded system programming)??

Comment: Oh and I forgot one thing. Is it the driver that I have to create or do I need a separate driver to make it work??

Comment: If you are using wifi you should not need to do any port wiring - just connect your PC to your wireless access point (via wire or wifi), connect your phone to it, and it's all a software project.

Answer (score 0):

- [Porting WiFi drivers to Android](http://blog.linuxconsulting.ro/2010/04/porting-wifi-drivers-to-android.html)
- [How to write an Android SocketServer to listen on wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054076/how-to-write-an-android-socketserver-to-listen-on-wifi)

Nothing is impossible, and the above links may help you
Wish you all success in your project

Comment: I guess you guys are talking about the port inside the PC for wireless connection. Well that port is for receiving and sending bytes through wi-fi. What I need here is after receiving information through this wireless port, I want the information to pass through another port which is a I/O port for joypad connection.I have given an example below:

Comment: for Eg: say I send the byte 0*B0 which is in hex(10110000 in binary) through wi-fi.Assuming that I have received that byte, now I want to send each bit of this binary information through the I/O port(assuming I/O port to be 8 bits) to make the computer make specific work for joypad manipulation, say "Press button D on direction right". I guess I am clear now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that using WP7.
We did a server side (PC) and a client side (WP).
The connection was by socket, using wi-fi. I think you should start studiyng socket and threads.